# Can ubuntu run on any other kernel

Tags: 11.10, kernel

Is there any kernel on which we can run Ubuntu??Like in some case Debian can run on BSD kernel (if I am  correct)
If it is possible how can I proceed

Answer (score 2):

No. There is too much linux only stuff in the default Ubuntu install.

It should be possible, but a lot of work, to create a distro similar to Ubuntu but based on the BSD kernel. But it's far more complicated than just *sudo apt-get install bsd*.

Answer (score 2):

The BSD ports in Debian are complete ports (different architectures, from a package management point of view). That means almost every package has to be built specfically for it.

A fair number of Ubuntu-specific features (such as upstart) aren't supported on BSD yet.